# Calling a class inside a loop in android

Tags: android, for-loop, android-asynctask

I just want to ask if it is possible that I can go back to my loop when I call an `AsyncTask` inside it. What I am trying to do is like the following:

1. I have an arraylist called `arrayListReportCode`, then it has two values for example as T001 and T002. I need to get all the details of each report code(done with this).
2. After I successfully passed(for uploading) the details I need to go back to the loop and do it again until all the report code's details is uploaded.(NOTE: `DoPostUploadFile` is another class)

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < arrayListReportCode.size(); i++){

       // get all the details of each report code
       new DoPostUploadFile(context, details).execute();

   }
   ```

Comment: Is it working? you did not specify if you had a problem with the loop. What I understand, you are trying to pass the details more than one time to the AsyncTask. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you will create a new instance of your AsyncTask each time you call it; it seems that it would make more sense to have an AsyncTask that you run once you have all your data...

Comment: @LuisLavieri yes, i was able to passed it to the asynctask but when the asynctask is done, it must go back to the loop but my program failed to do it.

Comment: yes, @kwishnu is right. You should try to load everything from one AsyncTask